# Keras: weighted average and std of a layer with constant weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

For developing a Keras model, I need to calculate average and standard deviation of the last layer. Consider my last layer to be a distribution of scores (scores from 1 to 10)  with dimension of (None,10) which is derived from a softmax activation function. Now, I want to calculate the weighted avg and std for this distribution(weights are the scores) as the output of the model. I could not find anything for it.
Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Can you maybe share the code of something you tried, or a minimal working example?

Comment: Sure. see, I used `w=K.constant([1,2,3,...,10])` and then `K.dot(distr,w)`. The problem was that the distr has dimension [?,10] but w has dimension [10]. So, it gives an error!

Comment: did you ever find an answer/